# How to zoom in an image on mouse up and zoom out on mouse down?

Tags: jquery, image, zooming

I want to zoom in an image on mouse up and zoom it out on mouse down. I've tried plugins which zoom some part of the image in new window but I don't need those. I want the image to zoom-in on its own window. Please help.

Comment: Seems backward, don't you think?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mouse up and mouse down?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the below demo helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="normal">
<img id="p1"  src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg"     onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()" />
</div>
<script>
function mouseDown() {
var m=document.getElementById("p1");
m.style.width="300px";
m.style.height="400px";
}
function mouseUp() {
var m=document.getElementById("p1");
m.style.width="200px";
m.style.height="300px";
}
</script>
<style>
.normal>img
{width: 200px; height: 300px;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```